# Dynamic programming - catching ball

Tags: algorithm, dynamic, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Balls are falling from the sky. We know at which location (on a
>   straight line) will each ball drop, and we know the time (in seconds)
>   at which will the ball reach the ground. We are trying to catch them
>   into a ball net, which we can move left or right, but each movement
>   costs 1 second. The initial position of a ballnet is always on the left (position 0). We are allowed to > drop (not catch) k number of balls.
>
> What is the highest score we can achieve?

My first attempt at solving this was a greedy algorithm:

```
if the |next ball position - current position of the ball net| > (time of the next ball - current time) 
     then attempts++
     if attempts>k
           print game over
else
     current ball net position = next ball position
     current time = time of the next ball
     score++
```

however my algorithm doesn't take into consideration that sometimes it's better to sacrifice some number of balls in order to reach a higher score in the long run. This needs an approach via dynamic programming, I think.

Is this problem a known one so I can find some help? Could you help me with this problem? I can solve this in a greedy way, however I am failing to do it dynamically.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I undestood the concept of droping `k` balls, could you explain it more so that I can help

Comment: @Sarmon Sorry, I phrased it incorrectly. You can see the number k as lives. Every time you miss a ball (not catch it), you lose a life.

Comment: It is better to try to solve it using brute force first, then you will see that you are repeating some work and go with memoization (which is a type of DP- Top-down), and then you can reiterate to write the bottom-up version

Comment: *which we can move left or right, but each movement costs 1 second* does it mean that for 1 unit of distance it costs 1 sec? or for any distance say 5 units it costs 1 sec too?

Answer (score 1):

For any given ball you can either catch it (if possible), or drop it and lose a "life". In order to decide if you should sacrifice a life for any given ball, create a decision tree in which you either catch the ball or drop the ball. Your tree will fan out, creating 2^n subproblems. At each level of the tree, you will have at maximum k unique subproblems, since you reach that point with anywhere from 1 to k lives. Create a matrix with the best score you can get for the ith ball with k lives left if you catch it. You can then reference those values to avoid excess work. When k and the number of balls are small, you can use dynamic programming to examine all possible combinations of catches/drops in a manageable amount of time.

Comment: How does this answer address the cost associated with each movement?